# issue with typeface in android

Tags: java, android

When I run the application on my phone (android 4.4.2 api 19) it doesn't work !

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // You can use here an API which was added in Lollipop.
            Typeface f = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"bogie.tff");
            TextView F = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alo);
            F.setTypeface(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat
https://codeshare.io/gnk8v
Gradle
https://codeshare.io/gkwXQ

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots of the code. Copy and paste the text into your post.

Comment: but logcat is not code . and when I tried to copy and paste it . it covers a great area !

Comment: Filter the logcat to extract only the necessary information.

Comment: how could I do that ?

Comment: I've done it . check the post again .

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to put all your typeface in your application class file. Initialise them on the onCreate function and use its instance as a public variable in any activity or fragment.
Do it once, use it multiple.

**Update**

The manifest file:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
...
</application>
```

Create a file with name App and add

```
private static final String OPEN_SANS_COND_BOLD = "fonts/OpenSans-CondBold.ttf";
public static Typeface openSansCondBold;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        openSansCondBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), OPEN_SANS_COND_BOLD);
    }
}
```

And us it at any place as:

```
textView.setTypface(App.openSansCondBold);
```

- use your preferred typeface
- put the ttf file in assets folder

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you well . in my code I have only one class and one onCreate method . where would I initialize it ?

Comment: You should rather use a typeface cache, and only initialise the typefaces when needed https://github.com/dlew/android-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/danlew/utils/FontCache.java

Comment: i've done this 
 Fontcache fc=new Fontcache();

            Typeface f = fc.getTypeface(this, "bogie.tff");
            TextView F = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alo);
            F.setTypeface(f);

 but still didn't work

Comment: could you show me all the imports because I have a problem in them .

Comment: import android.app.Application;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

Comment: a message "class or interface expected" appears to me for those two lines of code . private static final String OPEN_SANS_COND_BOLD = "fonts/OpenSans-CondBold.ttf"; and  
public static Typeface openSansCondBold;

Comment: This examlpe is totally working. Just locate your own ttf file and set it to the variable.
In your example should be
private static final String OPEN_SANS_COND_BOLD = "bogie.tff";

Comment: Sorry, i missed the super.onCreate(); Please check again

Comment: I suggest to put your ttf file under src/main/assets/your_file.ttf and use several ttf files to see if there's a file issue or the process that you are loading the font issue